# How do I install py2app onan off-internet PC

Tags: python, py2app

I have downloaded py2app, but the problem is that easy install seems to be an online installation, yet I am installing this on an off-line pc, so can't use easy install. I expected to be able to download an EXE file or MSI file to install it on my PC using a normal procedure to install a Python package, because the python packages that I have installed before have been from self running files.

The downloadable version of Py2app does not include any such self running file. It tells me to type $python setup.py install. Where do I type this? Into what command line?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows (and it seems that you're) you will need to go to the Run window (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) and...

type `cmd`

type `python setup.py install`

...to begin the instalation.

If you doesn't have Python on your `PATH`, the use:

`C:\PythonXY\python.exe setup.py install` (for example, in Python 2.7 use `C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py install`).

Also maybe you need to specify the `setup.py` path so you should do:

`C:\PythonXY\python.exe C:\Some\Path\setup.py install`.

If you're running any Linux distro then just open the terminal and type that command.

Hope it helps!

Comment: well i tried it and I got an error in CMD:\  can't find '__main__' module in d:\\py2app-0.7.3 (which is the directory where the setup.py file is. )

Comment: That seems to be a problem with `py2app`, not with the way you call it. Why are you trying to use that in Windows?

Comment: Apologies to all the Illuminati - I didn't know py2app was a Mac only package.  I naturally assumed that because I successfully made an .exe that i could make an app too. Please forgive me for not understanding the intrinsic impossibilities of cross-platform translation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download an install the following packages (in this order):

- altgraph
- macholib
- modulegraph
- py2app

All of them can be installed by first downloading and extracting the archive and then run "python setup.py install" with the current working directory set to the directory containing the setup.py file.

However... You appear to want to install py2app on a Windows PC, and that won't work because py2app does not support Windows (it cannot cross "compile" a Mac application bundle).

Comment: Yes I did want to.  Sorry.